# Keeping 2 tables in sync

Tags: mysql, replication, trigger

I need to write a trigger that will keep one table synced with 2 other tables. I have table_a, table_b and table_c on slave. The master has only table_a and whenever this table is updated on master, the two other tables on slave should also get updated using triggers or any other way.

In other words, I need to replicate only one table from this slave. Since there is no budget for one more server, I will use the same slave schema. Do I need to write after update, insert and delete triggers on table_a? What is the best approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case.  Are you basically saying you want to make three exact copies of a table on your slave?  If so can you add more "why" to your description?  Or, are these other tables aggregate summary tables of sorts?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a way to make three exact copies of a table on slave. Why? All three needs to have different partitioning. hourly, daily and monthly.

Comment: Perhaps 3 slave databases with identical tables (and different partitioning): `slave_db_a.tableX`, `slave_db_b.tableX`, `slave_db_c.tableX`.

Comment: Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a\G`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this scenario

- `table_a` has an auto_increment field
- `table_b` and `table_c` have table structure identical to `table_a`
- You are running MySQL 5.1+

you can create a Stored Procedure and a MySQL event instead of a Trigger

For the sake of example, let's say `table_a` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
    id not null auto_increment,
    ....
    primary key (id),
);
```

Create a Stored Procedure on the Slave to Copy Data to `table_b` and `table_c`

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Load_New_Data` $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `Load_New_Data` () 
BEGIN
    DECLARE min_id,min_idb,mid_idc INT;

    SELECT MAX(id) INTO min_idb FROM table_b;
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO min_idc FROM table_c;
    SET min_id = IF(min_idb < min_idc,min_idb,min_idc);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a_delta;
    CREATE TABLE table_a_delta SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE 1=2;
    INSERT INTO table_a_delta SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id >= min_id;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_b SELECT * FROM table_a_delta;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_c SELECT * FROM table_a_delta;

    DROP TABLE table_a_delta;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, schedule a MySQL Event on the Slave for the Stored Procedure to go off every 5 minutes starting 5 minutes after you create the event:

```
CREATE EVENT ev 
    ON SCHEDULE 
      EVERY 5 MINUTE 
      STARTS (NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) 
    DO 
      CALL Load_New_Data();
```

Don't forget to Add This to the Slave's /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=1
```

Comment: Does it take care of the updates and deletes taking place on table_a ?